# import data into r with some variables as list/vectors

Tags: r, variables, import, variable-length

I have some data I want to bring into R but I am not sure about the best way to create my variables. Basically, my variables are like so:

```
    ItemName: "c34"
    Item Height: 170
    ItemX = list(0, 1, 2, 3, 5 )
    ItemY = list(50, 30, 20, 10, 5)
    (...)
    ItemName: "c36"
    Item Height: 180
    ItemX = list(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 )
    ItemY = list(55.2, 30.1, 20, 10, 5, 0.1)
```

If not for the two variables that a variable length list, I will simply have a solution with a dataframe that has column names:

```
["ItemName", "ItemHeight", "ItemX", "ItemY"]
```

Now that "ItemX" and "ItemY" are variable length lists/vectors, what is the best way to import this into R so that I can do simple things like plotting ItemY vs. ItemX for every Item or do a regression ItemY~ItemX ?

Thanks

GT

Comment: What are we looking at?  A part of your file?

Comment: @Rich Scriven, yes that is part of the file I want to parse into R. I added the "list" keyword just to indicate but the values are actually stored on file as coma separate values.

Comment: You may want to provide a sample of the file and people can be more helpful about showing exact ways to import.

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking at your data from a different angle and use the tidyr package and approach.  Here is an article from R-Studio that explains the approach in more detail: [R-Studio: Introducing Tidyr](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/)

Your data format would be a data frame that would look like this:

```
ItemName  ItemHeight   ItemX   ItemY
"c34"     170           0       50
"c34"     170           1       30
```

By repeating the ItemName and ItemHeight columns and adding a new line for each x, y pair, you can have all your data and not get hung up by data with different numbers of x, y pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would try to read ItemX and ItemY as strings in a data.frame `df`, and then evaluate each element:

```
df[, c("ItemX", "ItemY")] <- as.data.frame(apply(df[, c("ItemX", "ItemY")], 
                                                 1:2,
                                                 function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
```

Don't know if this will work if you have different lengths of lists for every item...

Hope it helps somehow!

Comment: I am working on an attempt to post here later. Thanks